# Automated cloud service to merge video clips

Tags: api, video, merge, editor, cloud

Please, suggest me an online/cloud service with good API to dynamically merge about a hundred of video clips and assets.

Free or commercial.

I tried few online video editors, but they are mostly focused on manual work (basically, upload clips from a phone, make a movie and publish it on a blog/Yuotube), and I am looking for automated background merge and encode service to merge clips and publish it on my site or output to a file service.

Basically I need:

- manually or API: upload few dozens of source clips (to the Service)
- API only: dynamically script the sequences of clips (on my site) and pass it to the Service
- API only: get clips merged in the backround and output to any kind of a file server

Functions most wanted:

- merge clips into movie (automated, scripted sequence)
- insert audio track (i.e. one and the same video clip may have many optional audio tracks)
- output compiled movie to a file server (any one)
- include a customized (uploaded) picture or title into movie

Other functions like encoding and streaming are optional if I can send output movies to a third party service.

Please, can anyone recommend/suggest such a service?

Answer (score 4):

I found encoding.com, it seems to meet my requirements/
In case anyone would ever need it:
http://www.encoding.com/help/article/how_to_combine_multiple_video_files_to_a_single_one